# Why is System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox not working in my ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dialog, messagebox

I want to use a MessageBox to display a yes/no question, however it is not working. If they are any alternatives on opening a dialog box, please let me know.

Maybe the fact that it is a codebehind file makes a difference?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not working'? What happens? You should post your code.

Comment: What means "it is not working" ? Can you explain better your problem ?

Comment: Please define "not working". Also are you writing a web application or a desktop application? If it's the former `MessageBox` won't work.

Comment: Codebehind? MessageBox is for Windows Forms, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Basically it is not inheriting the System.Windows class and without that the messagebox will not work. I will post up the code.

Comment: @Seesharp: `System.Windows` is not a class. It's a namespace.

Comment: I also have tried using System.Windows.MessageBox;

Comment: @ChrisF is there any alternative for ASP.NET

Comment: @JohnSaunders is there any alternative for ASP.NET

Comment: @Seesharp: yes, go learn JavaScript and learn how that's done. JavaScript has `alert` and `confirm` functions.

Comment: The interesting thing would be if it "worked" though and the server had some message boxes popped up. ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys ye am a learn javascript, ye that would have been interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Maybe the fact that it is a codebehind file makes a difference?

Yes it does.  If you could display a Windows Forms MessageBox from an ASP.NET codebehind file, it would at best be displayed on the server, which isn't much use.

You need a javascript alert, or if you want to be more modern a jqueryui dialog or similar.  Google if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you there is no other alternative way I can do it without using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

> System.Windows.Forms.MessagBox

class will not show a messagebox in an asp.net application. You would need to write a javascript function. Check out the following link to raise various types of messageboxes.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/PopUp_Window_With_Buttons.aspx